# sed script to limit columns to 15 characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression, columns

Been trying to wrap my regex foo around this but not doing too well.

need sed script to format file:

```
844388240 920009 XXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
800450220 910003 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBB
736458376 947883 HHHH GGGGG
800450220 910003 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

9 digits(space)6 digits(space)up-to-15characters(space)up-to-15characters

result in:

```
844388240 920009 XXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
800450220 910003 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBB
736458376 947883 HHHH GGGGG
800450220 910003 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

each of the 3rd and 4th columns are truncated at 15 characters, however shorter values are passed untouched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\{15\}\)[^ ]*/\1/g'
```

Same thing with `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/\S{15}\K\S*//g'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=substr($i, 0, 15)} 1'
```

With `vim`:

```
:%s/\v\S{15}\zs\S*//g
```

With `cut`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <file.txt | cut -b1-15 | paste -d ' ' - - - -
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a champ.  I was missing a few things on the regex.  Thanks Sato....

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '
s/ /\n/g;
s/^(.{,15}).*$/\1/M3; 
s/^(.{,15}).*$/\1/M4; 
s/\n/ /g
' file
```